# Automating dirb for scanning several URLs

Tags: files, kali-linux, output, url

I have a bit of a problem making this script work and was wondering if anyone knew what the problem is. It is supposed to take a list of urls as input, scan them for sub directories and then output it to different files.

```
for i in $(urls.txt); do echo $i; fn=$(echo $i | sed "s/\///g"); echo $fn; dirb $i /usr/share/wordlists/dirb/small.txt > $fn; done
```

This script does correctly remove slashes for the new file but I get the error (translated from Swedish) that ": no such file or directory". Probably from the > $fn part.

```
for i in $(urls.txt); do echo $i; fn=$(echo $i | sed "s/\///g"); echo $fn; dirb $i /usr/share/wordlists/dirb/small.txt -o $fn; done
```

And trying to use dirb's own output I instead get an error like

```
"OUTPUT_FILE httpwww.website.com
(!) FATAL: Error opening output file: httpwww.website.com"
```

And some clarification regarding the one liners:
1) loop through a list of urls
2) output the url to terminal
3) generate filename from url using `sed`
4) output filename to terminal
5) run url through dirb and try to output it to file name

The supposed output file names look fine to me but aren't working. Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: do you have permissions to write files there? try `touch httpwww.website.com`

Comment: Yeah I have permission, running as root since I'm lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `bash` or `ksh93`:

1. Loop through the list of URLs
2. Output the URL to terminal

   ```
   while read -r url; do
     printf 'URL: "%s"\n' "$url"
   done <urls.txt
   ```
3. Create filename by removing unwanted characters from the URL (changing characters that is not in `A-Za-z0-9` to `_`, removing consecutive `_`).
4. Output filename to terminal

   ```
   while read -r url; do
     printf 'URL: "%s"\n' "$url"

     outfile="$( tr -s -c 'A-Za-z0-9' '_' <<<"$url" )"
     printf 'File: "%s"\n' "$outfile"
   done <urls.txt
   ```
5. Use `dirb` and direct output to file

   ```
   while read -r url; do
     printf 'URL: "%s"\n' "$url"

     outfile="$( tr -s -c 'A-Za-z0-9' '_' <<<"$url" )"
     printf 'File: "%s"\n' "$outfile"

     dirb "$url" /usr/share/wordlists/dirb/small.txt -o "$outfile"
   done <urls.txt
   ```

My version does a bit more sanitization of the filename than just removing forward slashes.

Also, the `echo $i` will invoke filename globbing (test with `i='*'`).

Since I don't have an example from your `urls.txt` file, it hard to say anything more about it.